# How does Principle Component Initialization work for determining the weights of the map vectors in Self Organizing Maps?

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, self-organizing-maps

I studied on a fundamental SOM initialization and was looking to understand exactly how this process, PCI,  works for initializing weight vectors on the map.  My understanding is that for a two dimensional Map, this initialization method looks at the eigenvectors for the two largest eigenvalues of the data matrix and then uses the subspace spanned by these eigenvectors to initialize the map.  Does that mean that in order to get the initial map weights, does this method take random linear combinations of the largest two eigenvectors in order to generate the map weights?  Is there a patten?

For example, for 40 input data vectors on the map, does the lininit initialization method take combinations a1*[e1] + a2*[e2] where [e1] and [e2] are the two largest eigenvectors and a1 and a2 are random integers ranging from -3 to 3?  Or is there a different mechanism?  I was looking to make sure I knew exactly how lininit takes the two largest eigenvectors of the input data matrix and uses them to construct the initial weight vectors for the map.

Answer (score 4):

The SOM creates a map that has the neighbourhood relationship between nearby nodes. Random initialisation does not help this process, since the nodes start randomly. Therefore, the idea of using the PCA initialisation is just a shortcut to get the map closer to the final state. This saves a lot of computation.

So how does this work? The first two principal components (PCs) are used. Set the initial weights as linear combination of the PCs. Rather than using random `a1` and `a2`, the weights are set in a range that corresponds to the scale of the principal components.

For example, for a 5x3 map, `a1` and `a2` can both be in the range (-1, 1) with the relevant number of elements. In other words, for the 5x3 map, `a1 = [-1.0 -0.5 0.0 0.5 1.0]` and `a2 = [-1.0 0.0 1.0]`, with 5 nodes and 3 nodes, respectively.

Then set each of the weights of nodes. For a rectangular SOM, each node has indices `[m, n]`.  Use the values of `a1[m]` and `a2[n]`. Thus, for all `m = [1 2 3 4 5]` and `n = [1 2 3]`:

`weight[m, n] = a1[m] * e1 + a2[n] * e2`

That is how to initialize the weights using the principal components. This makes the initial state globally ordered, so now the SOM algorithm is used to create the local ordering.

Comment: Are e1, e2 your principal components?

Comment: Yes, I believe that @Evan A used e1 and e2 to represent the first two eigenvectors, so that means they are in the direction of the principal components.

Comment: @TomAnderson: Great answer! Let me get this right, tho: My SOM is a map that has m x n nodes. Let's say my data matrix has dimensions i x j. This means, there are j input features, each of which is connected to a node by a certain weight. In your formula, `weight[m,n]` corresponds to a weight-vector with j entries, am I right? Also, each of the eigenvectors has j entries. If this is right so far, one last question: The entries of a1 and a2, did you just choose them arbitrarily in the interval [-1, 1] ? Is 0 a wise choice?

Comment: @Luc Your comments about weights being a vector the same size as the data dimension makes sense to me. Each i would correspond to each data observation, with j different values (e.g. j sensor readings). The range [-1, 1] was selected assuming normalised data. Using the linear initialization should not result in different results  than random initialization but should converge faster, so it is possible that tuning could improve it. I think it assumes the data is normalised, but if not normalised, the range might be centred and scaled to the data to make the map more the data from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The *Principal Component* part of the name is a reference to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis.

Here is the idea.  You start with data points placed at vectors of many underlying factors.  But they may be correlated in your data.  So, for example, if you're measuring height, weight, blood pressure, etc, you expect that tall people will weigh more.  But what you want to do is replace this with vectors of factors that are not correlated with each other in your data.

So your principal component is a vector of length 1 which is as strongly correlated as possible with the variation in your dataset.

Your secondary component is the vector of length 1 at right angles to the first which is as strongly correlated as possible with the rest of the variation in your data set.

Your tertiary component is the vector of length 1 at right angles to the first two which is as strongly correlated as possible with the rest of the variation in your data set.

And so on.

In practice you may start with many factors, but most of the information is captured in just the first few.  For example in the results of intelligence testing the first component is IQ and the second is the difference between how you are at verbal and quantitative reasoning.

How this applies to SOM initialization is that a simple linear model built off of PCA analysis is a pretty good guess for the answer that you're looking for, so starting there reduces how much work you have to do to finish getting the answer.